# Codeigniter active record update statement with a join

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This is the query that i'm trying to achieve via active record:

```
UPDATE `Customer_donations` cd 
join Invoices i on i.cd_id = cd.cd_id 
set cd.amount = '4', cd.amount_verified = '1' 
WHERE i.invoice_id =  '13';
```

This is my attempt at the active record:

```
$data = array('cd.amount'=>$amount, 'cd.amount_verified'=>'1');
$this->db->join('Invoices i', 'i.cd_id = cd.cd_id')
     ->where('i.invoice_id', $invoiceId);


// update the table with the new data
if($this->db->update('Customer_donations cd', $data)) {
  return true;
}
```

And this is the query that's actually getting produced:

```
UPDATE `Customer_donations` cd 
SET `cd`.`amount` = '1', `cd`.`amount_verified` = '1' 
WHERE `i`.`invoice_id` =  '13'
```

Why is this active record statement not applying my join clause?

Comment: I've never tried multi-chaining in Codeigniter's active record. I always use normal mode and it'd always worked liek a charm. You also test normal version of the query and give us the feedback.

Comment: Multi chaining in active record is easy. I do it all the time. The query that i'm trying to achieve works fine when run manually in my sql editor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about the solution below? A bit ugly but it achieved what you expected in your question.

```
$invoiceId = 13;
$amount = 4;
$data = array('cd.amount'=>$amount, 'cd.amount_verified'=>'1');

$this->db->where('i.invoice_id', $invoiceId);

$this->db->update('Customer_donations cd join Invoices i on i.cd_id = cd.cd_id', $data);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if you have a very complex query, I think to make the sql still human readable, just fallback to the `$this->db->query();`

Comment: I disagree. Human readable != safe and secure. active record prevents sql injection.

Comment: @Catfish "Human readable" can be very much safe if you use place holders.

Answer (score 1):

Even cleaner, since update accepts a third "where" array parameter:

```
$invoiceId = 13;
$amount = 4;
$data = array('cd.amount'=>$amount, 'cd.amount_verified'=>'1');
$this->db->update('Customer_donations cd join Invoices i on i.cd_id = cd.cd_id', 
  $data, array('i.invoice_id' => $invoiceId));
```